# Solutions of trigonometric equation $a\sin(x) + b\cos(x) = n$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a solution of the equation $a\sin(x) + b\cos(x) = n$ in rational numbers (i.e. $a,b,n,x$ are rational and positive) where $x$ is not of the form $90n^\circ$?

(This question was also there on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290626/integer-solutions-of-equation-sin-x-cos-x-n but it seems to have been blocked)

Edit: Basically, I just want an example where two irrational trigonometric ratios add up to give a rational number. But if x itself is irrational I cannot expand the functions of $sin$ and $cos$ properly. Hence I am looking for rational solutions of x. ($a$ and $b$ are optional i.e., they can be omitted. I just gave them in the hope that it would expand the answer set) 

I am just a beginner to trigonometry.

Comment: Did you read why the former posting of the same question was closed?  "*This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.*"  Without addressing what was pointed out as a problem with the other post, this post will soon meet the same fate.

Comment: hmm... alright.

Comment: Any more information to be provided?

Comment: It is better, but still doesn't address the issue of "what do you understand about the problem already" and "what attempts have you made to solve it."  For clarification, you require $a,b,n$ to be rational numbers and $x$ can be any real number?  Or do you require $x$ to be rational as well?  Rational in terms of degrees or in terms of radians?

Comment: I already put "in rational numbers". So $a,b,n,x$ are rational, and $x \not= 90n^\circ$

Comment: If $x$ is rational when expressed in degrees then it is not rational when expressed in radians (since $\frac{\pi}{180^\circ}$ is irrational).  If $x$ is rational when expressed in radians it is not rational when expressed in degrees (since $\frac{180^\circ}{\pi}$ is irrational).  We could define a new measure of angle for the problem that automatically rationalizes $x$ with respect to that new description, trivializing the problem, but that makes it uninteresting.  Again, you want $x$ to be rational, but with respect to what units of measurement?

Comment: May be of interest: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html

Comment: @JMoravitz: It was just a clue. I agree that it doesn't stop our search. If $p\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\arcsin(p)\in \mathbb{Q}$ then with $q=\arcsin(p)$ we have $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sin(q)=p \in \mathbb{Q}$ which is covered by Niven's Theorem, no?

Comment: @Ramashalanka My previous (now deleted comment) was in reference to a particular case which I hoped would lead to a solution.  You are correct in that Niven's (or whoever you wish to attribute the theorem to) does cover that and shows no solution.  I arrived at that step under the assumption that $a=b$ might have a solution (or equivalently that $a,b$ were omitted).  It seems then that a solution could only exist if $a\neq b$.  @ OP This question is certainly turning into a nontrivial problem.  I won't be able to continue on it tonight, certainly, but if I would guess no solution exists.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm okay with $x$ being rational either with respect to radians or degrees, as long as everything is rational.
$a$ and $b$ can be anything rational. (Though if there is no solution for the equation in rational $a$ and $b$, then we can expand the set into Reals

Comment: Here is one (rather obvious) one that meets your stated criteria that skipped my notice until now.  $1\cdot \sin(45^\circ) + (-1)\cdot \cos(45^\circ) = 0$.  If we were to expand $a,b$ to be any real numbers, then the problem of finding solutions becomes trivial.  You could take $a=\frac{m}{\sin x}$ and $b=\frac{n}{\cos x}$, $c=m+n$.

Comment: Ugh.. I forgot about that possibility. Should have included in the question that it should be strictly addition. Or else the numbers can just be canceled.

Comment: If a proof is not possible (That there can be solutions), even an example would be alright..